# Ocstore 2.3 shopPassword что это и где взять?

Tags: opencart, ocstore, яндекс-касса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Уникальный код, который знает только Yandex и Продавец. Используется интерфейсом инициализации оплаты** Где взять эту инфу знает кто?

Активировал родной модуль оплаты Яндекс Касса, не могу настроить и активировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще этот ключ использовался в старой версии API и это была просто рандомная строка.

`shopPassword` До 20 символов

> Секретное слово. Необходимо для формирования md5-хэша, который
>   передается в запросах Проверка заказа, Уведомление о переводе и
>   Уведомление об отмене заказа (сancelOrder).
>
> Рекомендуется использовать случайно сгенерированный набор символов.

В новой версии api яндекс кассы насколько мне известно он больше не нужен. Теперь вместо него секретный ключ, который генерируется в личном кабинете.

Скорее всего у вас устаревший модуль, его нужно обновить, если конечно обновления были. Либо попробуйте сгенерировать в личном кабинете ключ и ввести его в админку.

Comment: Александр, спасибо, помогли